# Extracting javascript variable and passing to next Jmeter request

Tags: jmeter

The Response data look like following within Script tag

```
var csrfParam = 
      "SKtEMgZtO0H8EYHkAZIQ4tcS5bC8jKrD=y2G5Of06jgHbkNdHNleFKiXoBMC62veD";
var securityTokenName =  "SKtEMgZtO0H8EYHkAZIQ4tcS5bC8jKrD";
var securityTokenValue =  "y2G5Of06jgHbkNdHNleFKiXoBMC62veD";
```

I'm using regular expression extractor as following:

```
Reference name :  MYREF 
Regular Expression : securityTokenName ="(.+?)" securityTokenValue="(.+?)"
Template :           $1$$2$
```

I'm access this variable in next Jmeter request to build the URL:

```
${MYREF_g1}  
${MYREF_g2}
```

Expecting to get MYREF_g1 =SKtEMgZtO0H8EYHkAZIQ4tcS5bC8jKrD 
and MYREF_g2 =y2G5Of06jgHbkNdHNleFKiXoBMC62veD 
But THIS is not working .

Any help would appreciated!

Comment: My suggestion is first you check with first regex `securityTokenName =  "(.*)"`   &  print the value using bean shell script(use beanshell post processor) `log.info(vars.get("REGEX_REF"));` if its work fine go to second.

Comment: securityTokenName = "(.*)" is not returning any matches. and thats the issue I'm facing .  I'm not sure if Jmeter doesn not see this since its part of javascript?

Comment: Can you please check the space part between **'='** and **(.*)** in `securityTokenName = "(.*)"`  regex because you may not considered space part in regex.   Try a wildcard test with regex `securityTokenName"(.*)"`, If  **=  "SKtEMgZtO0H8EYHkAZIQ4tcS5bC8jKrD** is coming as output jmeter is working fine otherwise it may have another issue.

Comment: Isn't there another way of doing this without using the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter?  I know SoapUI has a few ways.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you're misunderstanding what groups and templates are.

As per [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm)

> Template. The template used to create a string from the matches found.
>   This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups
>   within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is:
>   '$1$' to refer to group 1, '$2$' to refer to group 2, etc. $0$ refers
>   to whatever the entire expression matches. So, if you have in response
>   word “economics” and search for regular expression “(ec)(onomics)” and
>   apply template $2$$1$ than in output variable you will receive
>   “onomicsec”.

So your RegEx should look like:

```
var securityTokenName = "(.+?)"; var securityTokenValue = "(.+?)";
```

So

- securityTokenName will be stored in JMeter Variable `MYREF_g1`
- securityTokenValue will be stored in JMeter Variable `MYREF_g2`

[View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) has built-in RegExp Tester on ResponseData tab. You can also use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see what variables have been set by your Regular Expression Extractor.

Comment: adding var securityTokenName = "(.+?)" to reg expression extractor as suggested is not returning any matches. Thanks for suggesting Debug Sampler. somehow Jmeter does not recognize  securityTokenName  and securityTokenValue

Answer (score 0):

You need multiline regex match. Your regex will look like this

`(?s)securityTokenName="(.+?)".*?securityTokenValue="(.+?)";`

A sample test plan (it uses dummy sampler from jmeter plugins, if you don't have them it will faile) is [here](https://github.com/msapariya/jmeter-recipes/blob/master/regex-extractor/scripts/MultiLine.jmx).

This post [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Regular-expression-extractor-multiline-matching-td513660.html) discusses that simply having .*? will match multiple line, but apparently it did not work. [This post](http://lastbytes.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/grabbing-it-all-in-a-jmeter-regular-expression-extractor/) wast the savior.

Details are from the jmeter documentation are [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html).

Please note that I have removed the spaces around = to simplify my sample. Please change the regex appropriately.